# Drop part of a cell value after a specific character

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regexextract

I have one cell that contains a long string of several values separated by  "|".

**EXAMPLE** in Cell B5

```
title | time | location | cost
```

I need a formula that will show the value of B5, but only the characters before the first "|".

Is it possible to trim everything including and following a specific character?

Comment: See answer below - that should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B5, "[^\s|]+")
```

[image: 0]

- **`\s`** a space
- **`\s|`** a space followed by **`|`** character
- **`^`** the first
- **`^\s|`** the first match of a space followed by **`|`** character
- **`[]`** a group
- **`[^\s|]`** a group found before the first match of a space followed by **`|`** character
- **`+`** more than one character if possible
- **`[^\s|]+`** extract a group of characters before the first occurrence of a space followed by **`|`** character

Comment: if `^` is "the first", what would give the second or third?

Answer (score 4):

Split formula may fit your needs:

```
=split(B5, "|")
```

next step: use index to return any of splitted words:

```
=TRIM(INDEX(split(B5, "|"),1))
```

change 1 to your number, this is the index of a word to return

Comment: thanks for the input, but that isn't what I'm looking for. I don't want to keep the data remaining after the "|" and place it in other cells. I just want it to 'go away'.  Any other ideas?

Comment: `=TRIM(INDEX(split(B5, "|"),1))`

Answer (score 2):

You can just wrap it with trim

```
=Trim (split (B5,"|"))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need a formula that will show the value of B5, but only the characters before the first "|".

```
=TRIM(LEFT(B5,SEARCH("|",B5)-1)
```

The result is `title`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `=LEFT(B5,SEARCH("|",B5)-1)`.